# I have an error in php in a loop within a loop

Tags: mysql, php

I have this error:

> Warning: mysql_data_seek() [function.mysql-data-seek]: Offset 9 is invalid for MySQL result index 4 (or the query data is unbuffered)

I have a table messages, and I would like to display the most recent message. If user 1 is logged in, I would like to do this: For instance if user 1 sent an message to user 2, then user 2 to user 1, I would like to show to user 1, the newest message. So it would be the one that was sent by user 2. 
So, I have to display to user 1, the ids 2 and 3.

```
 <div class="maincontent">
    <!-- Obtengo datos -->
    <?php 
             $conexion=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root') or die('No');
    $db=mysql_select_db('carpe',$conexion)or die('no existe la base de datos.');

    $id= $_SESSION['id'];

    $multid_array = array();
    $outercnt=0;
 $consulta=mysql_query("select * from messages where id_from='".$id."'
 or id_to='".$id."' order by id asc");
    while($filas=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
        $id=$filas['id'];
        $id_to=$filas['id_to'];
        $id_from=$filas['id_from'];
        $status=$filas['status'];
        $text=$filas['text'];
        $time=$filas['time'];
        echo "lo primero: ";

        echo $id;
        echo " ";


        mysql_data_seek($consulta, 0);
        while($filas2=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
            $id2=$filas2['id'];
            $id_to2=$filas2['id_to'];
            $id_from2=$filas['id_from'];
            $status2=$filas2['status'];
            $text2=$filas2['text'];
            $time2=$filas2['time'];
            echo "es ";
            echo $id2;
                if($id_from==$id_from2 && $id_to==$id_to2 && $id2>$id){ 
                    $id=$id2;           
                    echo "el mas grande ";
                    echo $id;
                }
        }
         mysql_data_seek($consulta,$outercnt); 
         $outercnt++; 

        //Almaceno en un vector los mensajes a mostrar
        $multid_array[]=$id;



        echo "nuevo elemento  ";
        echo $id;
    }


    //Elimino duplicados
    $resultado = array_unique($multid_array);

    for ($x=0;$x<count($resultado); $x++){
        $id=$resultado[$x];
        $consulta=mysql_query("select * from messages where id='".$id."'");
        echo "arreglo ";
        echo $id;
        echo " ";
        while($filas=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
            $id_from=$filas['id_from'];
            $id_to=$filas['id_to'];
            $status=$filas['status'];
            $subject=$filas['subject'];
            $text=$filas['text'];
            $time=$filas['time'];           
        }




    ?>
            <h3><a href="#">Asunto: <?php echo $id?></a></h3>
            <span class="postInfo">Enviado por: <a href="#">De <?php echo
                         $id_from ?></a> A <?php echo $id_to ?> - <?php echo $time ?></span>
            <p><?php echo $text ?></p>
            <a class="more" href="#">Responder</a>
            <hr>
            <?php } ?>
            <hr>
        </div>
```

The first error is when I am trying to do:
mysql_data_seek($consulta,$outercnt);

I have another error (2nd) when I do:
$id=$resultado[$x];

this is the second error:
 Notice: Undefined offset: 1

I am currently displaying the messages, but I have those errors. thanks!

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to fetch row 9 but there is no row 9.

Check how many rows are returned before you try to fetch them?

Comment: I dont get it, For instance I have 10 rows, so I want to compare the first row with all the rows, then go to the second row, and do the same thing

Comment: @user1905120: If you have 10 rows, then you copy all them into an array and compare the array data - not via `mysql_data_seek`. - If not you let Mysql do the comparison server-side (yes the database server has been create for that).

Comment: So, I use the while from mysql, ( just like I have on this code)
and the second while I store all the rows in an array? how ?

Comment: First fetch all your rows with `while + mysql_fetch_assoc`. Then do whatever logic you need. Right now you've got a nested `while`-loop that can never be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($x=0;$x<count($resultado); $x++){
        $id=$resultado[$x];
```

it fetches $x element which can be non-existant,

right after for and before $id=$resultado[$x]; , paste:

```
if (!isset($resultado[$x])){
continue;
}
```